# How to check generic parameter associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

For the purpose of clarifying what am I asking about, please consider the following example:

```
protocol Food {}
protocol Meat: Food {}

protocol Animal {
    associatedtype Food
    func eat(food: Food)
}

protocol Funny {}

struct Cat: Animal {
    func eat(food: Meat) {
        print("Mewo!")
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to compare other animals that have specific conditions with `Cat`; Let's say we want to declare a function that compares a cat with: *funny* *animal* (comparing `T` with a constraint: it must conforms to tow protocols), the method signature would be declared as -in `Cat` structure-:

```
func compareWithFunnyAnimal<T: Animal & Funny>(animal: T) {}
```

It works fine, but what if I want to compare a cat with an animal that must eat `Meat` (comparing based on `T` associated type, which is `Food`) ? I tried to do -in `Cat` structure-:

```
// animal must eat Meat
func compareWithAnimal<T: Animal & T.Food == Meat>(animal: T) {}
```

but -obviously- it did not work.

How can I do such a comparison when it comes to the generic parameter associated type? Is there a workaround that requires to add more than one generic parameter?

Comment: Doesn't have Xcode with me but the IBM Sandbox accepted this: `func compareWithAnimal<T: Animal>(animal: T) where T.Food == Meat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use generic `where` clause to check if `T.Food` is of type `Meat`.

```
func compareWithAnimal<T: Animal>(animal: T) where T.Food == Meat {


}
```

Read more about [**Generic where Clause**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID192)